# i am making a login system in python but i am unable to resolve where '1' appears in screen from no where

Tags: python, authentication, sqlite

this is my code so far  i am using visual studio 2015 and python 3.5
any help will be appreciated

[this is the 1 i was talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCjXV.png)

```
 import sqlite3
    conn= sqlite3.connect("C:\\Users\\Kashif Mehmood\\Desktop\\logins.db")
    c=conn.cursor()
    from win32com.client import Dispatch
    speak = Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
    #def portal():

def login():
    check = True
    i=0
    while check and i<3:
        if i>0:
            speak.Speak("Your credentials were invalid \b")
        user=input(speak.Speak("enter your username\b"))

        passw=input(speak.Speak("Enter your password\n\t\t"))

        c.execute("SELECT *  FROM logins WHERE usernames = ? ;", (user,)) 
        data=c.fetchall()
        if len(data)==0 or len(data)==1:  
            print("invalid")
           # portal()
        else:
            check=False
            print("valid")
        i=i+1 
    conn.commit()

login()
```

Comment: if you put a `print()` statement on each line of your code, or step through in the debugger, you can watch the console to narrow down the source of the 1

Comment: i have tried that  user=input(speak.Speak("enter your username\b")) 1 comes after the speak function ends  but i dont know how can that happen